# How to check if string list contains anything other than some value?

Tags: java, spring-boot

If we have two simple lists where one have only one repeating value:

`List<String> states = Arrays.asList("Excelent", "Excelent", "Excelent");`

and the other one have one different value:

`List<String> states = Arrays.asList("Excelent", "Excelent", "Good");`

how can I check if list contains anything other than "Excelent" in this case?

It should looks something like:

```
private boolean check(List<String> states){
    //Some condition where we can say if there is any item not equal to "Excelent"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solve it.

You can for example streaming it and filter for values different to Excelent

```
private boolean check(List<String> states){
    return states.stream()
              .filter(item -> !item.equals("Excelent"))
              .count() > 0;
}
```

Comment: Counting the number of violating elements is not necessary. The condition can be determined as soon as a single violating element is found in the list and counting the rest of the violating elements is simply not necessary. A simple `states.stream().allMatch(item -> item.equals("Excelent"))` would suffice.

Comment: Yes that suffice. As told there are many ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `Stream.distinct()` ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--)) to first return distinct elements of the stream and then using the result to decide the next step.